# cocoapods 3.8.2 failed to generate the workspace file

Tags: cocoapods

I upgrade cocoapods to 3.8.2, and when I run `pod install --verbose --no-repo-update` (**which runs well when using cocoapods 3.7**), it shows the following error:

> Failed to send stats:  SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read
>         server hello A: sslv3 alert handshake failure

Why does it failed?

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting analysis, I find this is caused the old version of cocoapods-stats, just upgrade cocoapods-stats will solve this problem

> sudo  gem install cocoapods-stats